# Real valued homogeneous function on $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is it true that every homogeneous function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is either increasing or decreasing? Can this be shown formally?

Comment: How do you define monotonicity of a function of several variables?

Comment: For every $x,y\in R^n$, a real value function $f$ is increasing if $f(x)-f(y)\geq0$ for $x\geq y$ component-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Consider $f \, : \, \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$. Then for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(\alpha x) = (\alpha x)^2 = \alpha^2 x^2 = \alpha^2 f(x)$, so $f$ is homogeneous of degree $2$. However, $f$ is neither increasing nor decreasing.

If you restrict a homogeneous function on $\mathbb{R}$ to either nonpositive or nonnegative values, then that restricted function will certainly be either increasing or decreasing. Notice that $f(x) = x^2$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and decreasing on $\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$.

Also, I'm not sure what it means for a function to be increasing on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I was wondering whether a homogeneous function has an interior maximum/minimum. It seems that this cannot be possible.

Comment: I see. Consider the example I gave ($f(x) = x^2$). Or in, say, $\mathbb{R}^2$, consider $f(x, y) = x^2 y^2$. These are certainly homogeneous. Do they have interior maxima or minima?

Comment: Nope, they do not.

Comment: What about at $x = 0$, or at $x = 0, y = 0$? Or are we using different definitions of interior maxima/minima?

Comment: I'm thinking on global maxima/minima. Thus $x=0$ cannot be a minimum or maximum.

Comment: $f(0) = 0^2 = 0$. This is less than $x^2$ for any $x \neq 0$, and thus is a global (and local) minimum of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Could we assert that in general a homogeneous function can only have $\mathbf{0}\in R^n$ as an interior min/max?

Comment: Ooooh. Yes, I think so. Suppose some $x \neq 0$ is a local min/max of a homogeneous $f$. Then in any neighborhood of $x$ there will be some $\alpha x$ and $\beta x$, $\alpha < 1$, $\beta > 1$. But homogeneity will tell us that either $f(\alpha x) < f(x) < f(\beta x)$ or vice-versa. Does this make sense?

Comment: I see. So in general, suppose that the $arg\min_{x\in dom(f)} f(x)$ is non-empty. If there exist $x^*\in dom(f)$ such that $f(x^*)=0$, then $x^*=arg\min_{x\in dom(f)}f(x)$. Do you think this statement is true for any homogeneous function?